# converting base64 or image link to an image without saving the image

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup, smtp, base64

I am working on some price tracker that checks the price if changed to send an email to the user but I was wondering if I can convert an image link or the bsase64 of the image to a an image.png without saving the image on my file system. Here is my code of getting the image link and converting it to a base64(I know how to save an image on my file system and send it per mail).

**This is an example:**

```
    elif shop_type == "ebay":
        price = soup.find(id="prcIsum").get_text()
        converted_price = int(price[4:7].strip(","))
        image_desc = soup.find(itemprop="image")
        product = image_desc.get('alt')
        image_link = image_desc.get('src')
        .....

    image_base = base64.b64encode(requests.get(image_link).content)
```

and Here where I got stuck at the end

**base64 of the image if important**

```
image_base64 = "b'/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD//gAyUHJvY2Vzc2VkIEJ5IGVCYXkgd2l0aCBJbWFnZU1hZ2ljaywgejEuMS4wLiB8fEIy/9sAQwAGBAUGBQQGBgUGBwcGCAoQCgoJCQoUDg8MEBcUGBgXFBYWGh0lHxobIxwWFiAsICMmJykqKRkfLTAtKDAlKCko/9sAQwEHBwcKCAoTCgoTKBoWGigoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgo/8IAEQgA4QEsAwEhAAIRAQMRAf/EABsAAQEBAAMBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYH/8QAFgEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEC/9oADAMBAAIQAxAAAAH9IoF0aoFAIIKBBQhMAIWCpCqXRQhaUAEgpAAIZyBQJC2xdVRAFoABAEABISEoJKrRaUBKAAAEAQKQQSASjRqgQKAAQKIBAASkEhKNloECiGgAAEEEgAAGKXRaQAFABRACAIQACGdFpqAACgSgAgCAQACmKXQEpKSgBRACDjPnfoY5ZSgIIZ0XQgFEoCjJYAh1/jY8D7o9GHD145fEXp/dpyNMaNCAKFACQognDHm/FWeZwy4+4y9DzF184cntp9prSWgIBBQAQnSPL6aeZ5a9DqnDs7X6YfRcFY+Ny8jil+89OzetMyEKEKOt0Toeeeb5p5+Th7x26a846PIcnvR911s3l8OuPis+35q1qpmA4+GOLrR8x8lp1eIcpyc5y8xnppxVcrPU6y9v38vWsvs61OflNKB0487rZcHlGtHh/OaXRi1vlTsdo7HeO93Y4fOri8xep+sx3dFGrQdPxY6Xmy+325J49YseR85pzdyzv+kej3zt7l1s0M9cnMb7Y0FWgfMeDHe7IzldVzdhOZpy7GoaUFLSw0Ls1QqijhwceYsHIAtSRrIohRaWFpdFpVKIcUMozDOhRSi5IAUmihTVLSqUg4oSRIYpaUUXJmFFClFpqltKUSHDSSMjMNBQNZMgLRRDWjVLRaBDhpIZRnJRaBYSCilAXRql0FUIccMUyjMAtAQgC0BRoujVFoLDjgwJEhBaAgEhoAoprRoWi0HHCYKJmJQAUQkFAC0ujVLRaDEMiCSMihk0LKkhCgKLsui0qiM5qBImSBRC0QyEIFFLo1S0tCsxIVCZiUCDULCBDMFA1S6NC6CswgCSILCCw1BBDMAUtLo1Roo//8QAKRAAAgICAgEDBAEFAAAAAAAAAQIAAwQFERITFCAwEBUkYCIxQFBwgP/aAAgBAQABBQL2j/XYPPxj9+Zwo+6fl12LYn+CZ5nZZYqzd8B0qwhfWQclI+XwrZVnWnMHF21tLYWysx2rdbE/uXbgWN/C/hIb+C+S8W90ah2zAMK4x1sryAlwLLxZ0M1eSuMAwI+vPw8+8niW5dNUbb44azcoJZunlm2tafcLZ6huy38PY4JwgLsjT0+mWP0BS9GTPb8+1uFxCxOu59J8hjX1JH2OMsfcUCPvI+8tj7W5o2W7RbHcntwmDkuBqreBgYqzpq0lvjyL/Hweoijg6m7IXP8ALaZZ/KUVhacsF8m7AuajAoulSeOv3swWG0TzRskCbHavTe+a7Q3sZ3czq5nhYRalnTHWC3HWesHNuVa88txXqxnjM8cxuUuazvGXgZRopfAXrX1cxaLngRoagYq8e+/ISiNmpy2YJfkOantuMVGMFU2daC5gAwM7mcsZwYFgri0EwYzQYdjSrWWcJq4usrl2vAhw42vJHhYXLiW5GZjUCmgfBkX146NtqZZtbet99t5ooR6gMdZe9b0MxIHkI6Nxtcf8XxGLjuYmBaYmqsMTUSvV1CJhVLBSgnQQKJx7GpBi0Syiu1Kceur4tti2XLXrsoz7ZbwmCKS3XkwFuBW5i0NBjGelUgYtYniUTr9ePkHxmH6f0nUQAfpZ/cD/AMD/AP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJD/2gAIAQMBAT8BCf8A/8QAHBEAAgIDAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAREAECAwQHAx/9oACAECAQE/AfOnAYOAxcjobHZshhRZDSYsnFQ+cY3K1F7n/8QAMxAAAQMCAwUGBQQDAAAAAAAAAQACEQMhEiIxEDJBYXEEEzAzUYEgI0BCsUNwkaFQUoD/2gAIAQEABj8C/cC37EknRCi2nImJlB7DLT/hC1lwFOipy6BfUqzwei4rIL81IDV823NHugGN4TdYe0S+mTrxCDmEFp4/Vu6IcVZqgptSmbhY+zsy/hXLR7rufUry09gmxstE5jxlJmRwQIMg/SXsszx7XREPWRn8lWwhbxW8VLxiHNS1x2Mon9Qwq1DWHYp5HZidEhBw0N1VHAtafyiUQJJPBNnn42aowe68yegVg4rLTb7lWLR0C8xyuSoFyUTylWpOhTUqUaY5vXzu2s6Mur1K1Q9IRHYabwwDddcq7dgLbEaFEtdNhilXfHQJ0km2qYOSe6PQIkAE+k3Kmm0z6prBwHgX2cFd4Xd0nZHs1/lXcT7/AAXWZ4Cu5x6BeSXdXLJ2ag2/+t1gccvpCANRxjn8BLfRZlKYxhcZaNUS3UlaFQWlrVmK08Ad4YnRb0L7ig5jcMOj+lvFa7OyOdpdpR2W+HRbpVmITCu5XusgCuAsjrplKqC26qGqTjJtxxckxliRqfBxVTA0WRrnf0j3VFvugasQNFSe9zRkAut+egT8DXHDDllpAKLDoruWIatcForNK3VdZirrdCsAtPAw1Whw/Cmm2/rqfCx08+H7F5Yb1KzVWjpdTjc7hCkRGw2N1u7LlQ64W6FotPrtP+w//8QAKRABAAIBAwMDAwUBAAAAAAAAAQARIRAxQSAwYVFxgUCRwVChsdHx8P/aAAgBAQABPyHsL750uly+2fVJK7ZDrPoq1rtH6GaHeqVKlSvoiFoSHaDm+9XdP0Q0P0G+kh1j2rl6XohWEuk1PMm84Iy+0anevpuLKsG8uIVW+FnMF4ZRSSLqzd/mPGg3tcBtaVCL58E2WPEcsa5oQmCOxZlpt2cx2Q6DoOrnsug63LhLK0N7RUKs4CLRS+0VkTxFwD34fD4l7AgUX7J+cpNwFArh9GO7eFPDUcFT7ZyH2Zgp++PkzGb/ABCZAsTZJcJnRfSy5ei5cuXLlyjsHnEE3/pC9tTQ4p0RFP7cufjzEUUxvqxYnLiEUEfMNKL5mOworw8Q8dhhzsfw6FmMbu8a3BTGYIDlZjOH40AK2hKcz0FmntehOInYJgW4PM/jMxPPzDPxvkp2XuMbAbu/gam5j3ZnsDEDddbkv3JWlEpFEuyjDl7UWlW/QxECA+TJyx4UwTeX6VWG4ygVQ3BMzjEjq3MMpnNQYLsEH2D/AGAKBdbBBYt8iggbBqv17FNbfaC2GPkPdmxH2gcDdsZGxhn7uWgnYrD1MVJQTzF/2kN3vsRIons/xCmE0yJ3eqzCqq0AGycQOqAFqO5zL92IN4vDiFsUwlvQcxvEh555fT2giqtKe0No8uGDe02ivQ9CbnFCiVKla3CmOX3TbMgIVwlk4MNzaq5u43X4ZRK2/wBpk3T3nORuuKw/3CWxp4gmxA9tR5TB+YsV4mwJ+NOb3XcozDWdGNygS4rXBZgB4PMSTEqJuS4BTUsro8MfxHABe4wQ0qHQYuzTFqw37tG+Bxa5jMGBjf8AyZQmL+mNonkfLhDygwOa/MpqXvFmvYS6rVCRevfDZ+SXu6fhRNjZN4hD5fgnJlmzS/GqeNAcEB6QNEvQAGHyhs9V4Y20Xha/cZUqB15mUAfPc/7iZj4OQT40H+koFNWRQkpyGzHEWbBiDxCtoBuFnpQ0hbjduM2b7UNsZU2EqtN2lSpUqVKlStRXPbTEzfeHhMOyegIy9L0SGGJcqVK7RodpiSokeo6r6bh0HfNBq56L0e4aHaJRdx0dR0uXqOI9shodu46v0pDtsC3oP0xDuP0t6kIdtYNl56H6QYQ6Tun0ZDoO49Z0O0NHS5fQQ0NR7b1G+l9k1NLg/QmrDscdRqQh1f/aAAwDAQACAAMAAAAQhMhABMAAwEBElIhMAACAyADEAcKAwAAACICICBiMQIzEyMCIgMCMCMjMDISMwIhIBAiIAAAAhACASIAMSMDMQEhMSMQAAAgEQMzICEiIgEwETEZIREzESISEQEbsEvgMyMzMhIJetxMgziau5sWAoI/mwmJuAMpmJnvlyGgqhiZnq6vg5IbR3iiRHxomYMhPne2VYi4ipAyQ6LXfbu5m4gQMbiKO6uYmqiCEwmquZqKqJiJIjC7u4iamJmKMBIKmairuKmIijEhKLuJuLmqmpEwM7uou7qaq4oQARu4iYmZqYmKAQAKqKmYm4uYsgIympqTmZmqiAkhuampuqiIm5sEE6qomouJi5qzMhubmbi4iriov/8QAHxEAAgEDBQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEREDBBICExQHBR/9oACAEDAQE/EPOkiB9BCZMjWLiqqIRyzNxVXw2XBJObqqidUUgzYWqBbDcifQnXHuH/xAAgEQEAAgICAwADAAAAAAAAAAABABEQISAxMEBQUWBw/9oACAECAQE/EP5Kemy8LCKmn0BsqKICQ/MHxXN4NcEVqdFs6c7ncqVLJSG8aFwV7ZWoNiaFcFiwWSs1KhAqMFkICBlam3WGuVcsgyzgYWOyBUcdc35FQhBSHpniP0w+ieI9Ml/a/8QAJxABAAICAQQDAAMBAAMAAAAAAQARECExQVFhcSCBkaGxwTDR8PH/2gAIAQEAAT8QlSoQJpBl95SWfCqxUqbJdQZqJhQSMqagjZkG4kCpUDFYqEECGKJUGoPzSVUGETHEuXCJElsawEg/GsEOsEEojlJxgfKokCsM3m4MY+UqJGKZeTBCGAip1P8AlcuWSyWS5cuXCMuHnPfLE+BAi712hBDDi8HGalSpWS0MFSsObx6lTUqVKlYIHYuEbMDFy5qHwDtOdV2hx/zcKlM3mnA/AhBCHwuXDF5L6w+DNy/jcNxj8emRAghA1Hj5kJcvF4YS5cWXBxpgUUZCVKnE8oA9ZRCGTpHHSHZdx4ljVTrgwcyo4uNJSXd1OWyKBzKOQ2sbudhm2lNVRv6gcgUupaf5GLYS5eGVcqUxQgTSLDjA7qat74PBN4JdO8LEzk1NyrlMB1gBcoO1NBC+bJKE59xRdPQ7CB70BWbQX6S91qFg9hxLULnYqEpx2MB31z617hqIGlCg/c4rmzko7hbEOQKI70q6PQfbL5/K1pdp3L3X5A3vbbGMqE4wIsWDBhW0EjBhxKghFJZUViDAo3DTXEuLDRuIrbHa9uiIuQUJyNOyGPxHatDg7ysI2qvdwWhHXoPRA3ro/gdUWJ5hoMRSzeypsRPqM63yl/BHyUSdg8P1/pBLZgS7SNPCahWW3DYQy/AfUUSPJGqzQN6dQgE1F7RwjKQPaFOCCwvIXFUIvctUF3wYNJ7TnU555EH6wpe222/iDAYBBovvrt1mss82f1FlArj/AFXDEaugKTq6ulS+9S/dQKlWJYnCRYicXP2uYnQTadsGsFaQ2K/SvuGNS/rA2PCI1/5lcwcTb6QLdde81G3ZSiXs6MudQYUocfob9Rr5WrgpkoVa21RzDYO1TtacexgThCNkqsX3g6l1gQiPcXuS9CFWP5R/DcZAs/8AYaiaO91H/YFgzup/FQNO10f7cHFN1Sj+Jdfbz/cVkiAFthevyaGHwkOp9N+rgi/htASxtrVbgSgCM0lmiVYQ2TZ748S2FDjC/dQ+lABB2FaV7/nEej6qmEUIhilmgNiPjmFkIV1BU8UlX9RDquwH9wx5hakNtfVzpQGNlFEWMUKdl/b+oO+BN1AA1ddLg5dUK1SlV/8AviNYpiuV1X224JepzDbNRqG0xVDqsepHuEKPUQX1kAZQt2t7VAfcaRrzP9xZrR4iVbvaPHO45uobMPFeuNr+Iw07oAftZWEuRg/i/wCSDUG2sQOmItU1yX3hNvSmlsaHRT7hsIpQAAavsETVtu+5yEPbN077xUaLK+G0f8mhHu95QUK2nED3Vkui0jRenYRklOVKAA/v9hN2HCjLGT791FCu4pYfRI0I2St0BxOO1fbAynaHEWGkuooBF0q+BepEAUCiFAmzqJFNFfM4WBHQif0xSqi+AwDqMu4Jd0Do5Yj9K7uQONmleX7ilIoNqS+Yvbv1FbunCck5YvuEbW4vSsQ5M57ntFCgl4shgJAtZRluDe5ZRceCUdfdxNSA7xWesENxIjPAteF9Jx4g7DpHqeTUEQGNPhI8Ot4HqaMg4u3bT2ODwSgpCoNStsKQSpUqOz07oC0HouIIl5A/2XChTZX60H2RsToQptej1/I5zdIrV8nSXJXsw/WVD9VwN9V1prHohVKv5h1WGuua6v5Bpy1ugf3mXH47V5n+YUCsu+I8Dr7R/LsVK+j/AGFBV3g4V8plPtHcuBUL0JQ3BXX5QHA/JRElJE1G1AGWOWiBLZ3AIn1AwHsYO1i14uEGBVQgQ1ioURKB3dre6VEsd1o9IWo/rvoV/iVLpj/boRu9FdV0W2brfV7ykGoO4itTj2wwpeA1BLYXWiMG0IG61O3jvcW/1kaTDWyJ6lXRrsYbqfUDaH1DtVA1Gwe0rJWFIQHIFQI1rSQhB1KuEOMVhnCJSdRNaXUrQDrjUO4vUA6L6iNQhbKFPUFTBuJTGg8wLNRJ0hgqU9pUogQlSoGBgQhxKhKz7YCCylcTbqHUCoNymVqBATpK1hYtYDgyWTA41z3hxDiEOMVDKzmPNdZ0mzNrmkuzRuWlWe4LCKU/sYNS4A5idZyizrBlwlwNw1DUuDvAwMEPje6wfNHGBpiiwaw3ctLdpbLZdKzcuDuDDI7iwGKGCHxq2VXDHbeAbjgDe24FQW3UIy7j7g1FM9YSoS+0PMUhzBiihBhi4OWVNCJqaB3OTkSpzCGDWGLLyObgzvBgwYooMGDgly81dwoNRbh1jGMvUOYax3xesVHBBl6hjygwcFqKDBlwYMvF4ZoZVAF9ymBh4wHWKiMLJcHWekcXuXgZcuDgUUGDL+KzCxLnTDEiZGd2SrhqEeIxcDLly4MuDUUUGDBigy5eWMIxjhU4NcwXrCprHlKwzZVzBrcYG9TiKOsLQZcG4ooMUGD8S4uCMYsDuMDUqcTiBt2lw7IcRlawmoxjhcuKDDAGDB1Bgy8dM94zpHlnT4uE5TpOkOI4Y8MY6R4h8BxD4A4hxCd8f//Z"
```

**image link**

```
image_link= "https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/zY0AAOSwZJBX-Miu/s-l300.jpg"
```

**I want to display this image for example in the mail that I send**

[image]

**sending an email**

```
subject = f"Price of your {product.title()} has Changed"
body = f"Your {product} price has changed to (EUR {price}) please check {Url} \n \n{image_link}"
msg = f"Subject: {subject} \n\n {body}"

server.sendmail(user_email, test_mail, msg.format(user_email, test_mail, subject, body).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: To an image. an `io` object?

Comment: Try `io.BytesIO(requests.get(image_link).content)`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I tried it I only get the ```io``` object not the image I am looking to get the actual image

Comment: Still not sure what you want, be more specific.What might be the **type** of your `"image"` in python?

Comment: There is no type named `"image"` in python.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA my image first is a link that been pulled out of a site. I want to convert the link to a an actual image with the type of png or jpg without saving it on my file system for example for the type: ```image_name.png```. I hope this explanation might help

Comment: Still not clear that.If now you get your `"image"`, how would you use it?For example, you want to send a picture with email.What type of parameter should be received when you try to send your image?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA yeah I want to send the actual picture in the email.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I am getting the link of the picture which when I open I get the picture but I don't want to send the link of the picture.  what I want is  the actual Picture to be send for example I want to be able to attach the raw picture that you see to the email that I send without saving the picture on my computer.the ```"image"``` is an itemprop on ebay that allows me to pull the picture link and the name of the product you get this when you go to inspect picture.

Comment: I know what you want to do.But I don't know what the type of `"image"` you need.Send an image by email. Sure, the question is what the type of `"image"` in `email.send(image)`?

Comment: An email message is just text. To embed an image into an email message, you have to use a content type which allows this, like HTML, and within that link to the attached image. As a crude fallback, send a text part and an image part and hope that the recipient's email client will render them both. (You can add "Content-disposition: inline" to the attachment to suggest that it should.)  Either way, you need a multipart MIME container, with the actual message in one part, and the image in another.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA (I added some more code might help) and the ```"image"``` that you see  in the ```image_desc=soup.find(itemprop="image")``` is the value that I pull to get the link/name of product of the image in the site if eaby when I right click inspect the image. and i am very sorry i am bad at explaining

Comment: @tripleee Okay I am going to try your solution thanks.

Comment: Joining fragments of text is not a sustainable way to create a valid email message. For really simple messages, you can try, but especially if you don't know exactly what you are doing, don't do that. Use the `email` library to create a valid MIME structure. It's not hard to find examples, right in the documentation for a start.

Comment: @tripleee I tried your method and did some research but from the examples that I found they have saved the image already on their local file and the point of my question is if I can send the Image without saving it on my local file. should I update my code (did work on many solution for an hour but nothing seem to work)

Comment: The difference is minor; instead of reading the bytes from a file, just attach them. That is, instead of `with open(imagefile, 'rb') as fp: msg.add_attachment(fp.read(), maintype='image', subtype='png')` you do `msg.add_attachment(imagedata, ...)` where `imagedata` contains the bytes of the image (what you got with `requests.get(image_link).content`).

Comment: I added an answer with details now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An email message is just text. To embed an image into an email message, you have to use a content type which allows this, like HTML, and within that link to the attached image. As a crude fallback, send a text part and an image part and hope that the recipient's email client will render them both. (You can add "Content-disposition: inline" to the attachment to suggest that it should.) Either way, you need a multipart MIME container, with the actual message in one part, and the image in another.

Depending on which you choose, you want to end up with either

```
From: you <your_address@example.net>
To: some recipient <victim@example.org>
Subject: Price of your Zircon-Encrusted Tweezer has Changed
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foobar"

--foobar
Content-type: text/plain; charset="ascii"
Content-transfer-encoding: 7bit

Your tweezer price has changed to (EUR 0.01) please check https://nopunctuationorlinebreaks.example.net/tweezer

--foobar
Content-type: image/png
Content-disposition: inline
Content-transfer-encoding: base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD//gAyUHJvY2Vzc2VkIEJ5IGVCYXkgd2l0aCBJ
bWFnZU1hZ2ljaywgejEuMS4wLiB8fEIy/9sAQwAGBAUGBQQGBgUGBwcGCAoQCgoJ
CQoUDg8MEBcUGBgXFBYWGh0lHxobIxwWFiAsICMmJykqKRkfLTAtKDAlKCko/9sA
etc

--foobar--
```

or a similar `multipart/related` where the first part is `text/html` with an `<img src=cid:whatever>` where the image attachment has the same `cid` in its MIME headers.  Or, of course, if the image already exists on a public web site, simply link there:

```
body = f"""<html><body><p>Your {product} price has changed to (EUR {price}). 
Please check {Url}</p>
<p><img src="{image_link}" alt="Now with sentence punctuation!" />
</p></body></html>
"""
```

Joining fragments of text is not a sustainable way to create a valid email message, though. For really simple messages, you can try, but especially if you don't know exactly what you are doing, don't do that. Use the `email` library to create a valid MIME structure.

```py
from email.message import EmailMessage

# ...

    elif shop_type == "ebay":
        price = soup.find(id="prcIsum").get_text()
        converted_price = int(price[4:7].strip(","))
        image_desc = soup.find(itemprop="image")
        product = image_desc.get('alt')
        image_link = image_desc.get('src')
        .....

    imagedata = requests.get(image_link).content

    # ...

    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = f"Price of your {product.title()} has Changed"
    msg['From'] = user_email
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(test_mail)

    msg.set_content(f"Your {product} price has changed to (EUR {price}). Please check {Url}\n")

    msg.add_attachment(imagedata, maintype='image', subtype='png', disposition='inline')

    server.send_message(msg)
```

If you want to send HTML with just a link to an online image in the `<img>` tag, obviously you can omit the `add_attachment()` call; then you'll need to specify the message type as `text/html` instead of `text/plain`.

You don't need to `base64` anything explicitly; the `email` library takes care of encoding everything for SMTP. (You'll need to make sure you tag everything correctly, though. For example, I assumed your image is `image/png` but it could obviously be some other type.)

Comment: I know *tweezers* is plural but I had to bend things a bit to fit with your template.

Comment: I had to guess about several of your variables so this is obviously untested.

Comment: worked like a charm thank you very much I search so much online about my problem but I didn't find the right answer neither didn't find anything about the ```email.message``` lib one more time thank you

Comment: The `email` module is part of Python's standard library and has extensive [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) with [examples.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)  Unfortunately it is not very newbie-friendly, and the web is shock full of poor, obsolete, and/or outright incorrect examples and explanations.

Comment: okay I am going to read about it thanks again I did the ```msg.set_content (f"Your {product} price has changed to (EUR {price}) please check \n {Url}")``` the content example in your code didn't work so I only put the str in brackets thanks again

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I really hope you would put a full stop or at least a comma after `(EUR {price}).`